# How to resolve "couldn't find "libflutter.so" crashing issue?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My flutter app is crashing a lot in production when I deployed app on Google Play store.

From the log, I can see the following error message:

```
couldn't find "libflutter.so
```

I have read lots of questions and solutions about this issue and I have also applied the following solution which is described in various places on internet.

```
buildTypes {
         release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64'
            }
```

But the above solution does not seems to work, because I can still see lots of crashes.

Comment: I have this issue too. It has started happening only recently.

Comment: It seems to be very old issue without any solution yet. I have read several related issues on Github about this, but none of their proposed solution seems to work.

Comment: Any dice on a solution? @JohnOsborn

Comment: @MichealCWallas  Did not find a proper solution yet.

Comment: I still get these, but they are always for the same devices: a Nexus 5x and a rooted OnePlus8Pro. The crashes always appear shortly after I publish a new release. My guess is that these are test devices, so I just ignore them.

Comment: Several months ago, I was getting legitimate crashes, but I fixed those by updating gradle.